# How to Put Address bar url in href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

I have 1000 posts and want to put facebook comments on every page. The facebook plguin requires a url `value` inside the `href` attribute. I don't want to manually put the url 1000 times.

There are certain ways like putting `expr:href='data:post.canonicaUrl'` in blogger.However, i am putting the code outside the main wrapper,hence blogger is unable to catch up the post url.

Is there anyway in which the `href` attribute automatically catches up the value of the address bar url.

Answer (score 1):

Following script will replace the `href` attribute of all anchor tags with the current url

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++)
 anchors[i].href = window.location.href;
```